# При соприкосновении с объектами игрока начинает трясти

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, online

У меня онлайн игра, использую Photon PUN 2. Проблема в том, что при соприкосновении игрока с объектами по типу коробок, у которых есть `Rigidbody`, игрока начинает трясти, но только от вида другого игрока, а для игрока, который встал на коробку, всё выглядит нормально. Также после этого рассинхронизируется позиция игрока.

[Видео](https://youtu.be/S8yrtjaS3uU)

Через скриншот и видео также не получилось передать, что было это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На игроках такие настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На коробках такие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]